# ALAuth check isn't working

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

I am trying to check if a user has allowed my app permission to access Photos (in Objective-C only) but I get the following errors:

```
Error 1: initializer element is not compile-time constant
Error 2: Excepted identifier or '('
```

Here's the code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

//(Error 1) ALAuthorizationStatus status = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];

//(Error 2) if (status != ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    //show alert for asking the user to give permission

}
```

**These codes are in my .m file, how do I fix this (please include the code)?**

Comment: You can't just stick code out in the middle of nowhere. Provide some context.

Comment: @rmaddy I fear that _is_ the context. He _did_ just stick the code in the middle of nowhere. That's the problem.

Comment: "please include the code" No. Stack Overflow is not a "please send teh codez" site. If you have a reasonable programming question, ask it.

Comment: Always [search on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjective-c%5D+initializer+element+is+not+compile-time+constant) before posting.

Comment: I marked where i received the errors in the code

Comment: @rmaddy i did and i couldn't find anything to help me specifically

Comment: We didn't ask where the errors were from, we asked where this code is. Is that the 100% complete .m file? Perhaps a basic tutorial on Objective-C would be prudent at this point. Learning the basic syntax and file structure now will save you a lot of time as you develop your app.

Comment: Yes that is the entire .m

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I made a tiny mistake. I forgot to add the `viewdidload`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BaseViewController.h"
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

@interface ViewController14 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController14
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ALAuthorizationStatus status = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];

    if (status != ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        //show alert for asking the user to give permission

    }
}

@end
```